# Is it possible to run R Shiny app from Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: r, shiny, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google's Colaboratory to run an R script.

[image]

I ran both cells as shown in the photo above, but after clicking on the link bellow the second cell, an error page appears:
[image]

Does anybody maybe know the solution? Or is it just not possible to run a Shiny app thorough Jupyter Notebook?